# HTML Radio Button Option with Dropdown In it

Tags: html, radio-button, dropdown

[image: Radio Button Option with Dropdown in It]

Is it possible for HTML to have an radio button option with dropdown in it? I am not familiar much if JS (including jQuery) or CSS could make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

That is just plain HTML - the select is not "in the radio"

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="rad1">Professional staff at</label> <select><option></option></select> FTE<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad1">Academic staff at</label> <select><option></option></select> FTE<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad1">PhD student at</label> <select><option></option></select> time<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!